# Fetch data from form and build a multidimensional array of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple html form that is structured something like this:

```
<form name="test" action="">
    <tr class="selectable" data-selected=false>
        <input type="hidden" name="product[gate][id] value=<? echo $pid?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="product[gate][amount]"/> 
    </tr>
</form>
```

I need to collect each tr row that has "data-selected" true.

So that I would end up with some sort of an array that I could then send to server with jQuery POST request.

Something like this:

```
products => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        id => 1134,
        amount => 2
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        id => 1134,
        amount => 3
    )
)
```

I don't know how to build a multidimensional array with js, I am not at all familiar with JS objects or JSON, either. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $trs = $("tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("selected");
});

var products = [];
$.each($trs, function(i, $tr) {
    products.push({
        "id": $('input[type="hidden"]', $tr).val(),
        "amount": $('input[type="text"]', $tr).val()
    });
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eg99X/1/)

The `products` variable should then be in a format you can use in an AJAX call. You may want to use nicer selectors than `input[attr]`, a class for example, in your working code.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a way to go, but I am unable to serialize products variable. http://jsfiddle.net/eg99X/2/

Comment: With this method you don't need to serialise the products variable. The code here is doing what serialize does to the whole form, but excluding the rows with the `selected` data parameter set to false.

Comment: I know this is getting beyond the scope of the question, but if you don't mind me asking. - Lets say I have two separate forms and I would like to append this form data to another one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the necessary data within your form tag. If any data you do not want to post then it should not be inside `<form>`.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

More info : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/